# rails unit tests for model returns invalid result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following model defined in my Rails application:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif\\png\\jpg)\z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIf, PNG or JPG image'
  }
end
```

Following is the schema of this model:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :image_url
      t.decimal :price, precision: 8, scale: 2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Following is the unit test for my model:

```
test "product price should be greater than 0" do
    product = Product.new(title: "abc", description: "abc", image_url: "abc.gif")
    product.price = 20.00
    assert product.valid?
end
```

When I run this test using bin\rails test:models, it fails saying that the assertion failed. Since I am setting the price to be greater than 0.01, it should have passed. Can someone explain why the test is failing here?

Answer (score 0):

Pardon my mistake, I found out that the regex for validating my image_url field was wrong. I had to use the `|` operator instead of `\\`. Once I fixed this error, the test was running fine.